# The best way to check parameter for directory in Python

Tags: python, path

My script should accept both relative or absolute paths (just directories). This is the first time I'm doing it in Python. I'm going to stick to the the following code:

```
 def _Dir(pass_dir):
    get_path = pass_dir
    #gives full normal path
    full_path = os.path.abspath(get_path)
    #check if it exists
    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
       print "path exists"
       return 1
    else:
       print "path doesn't exists"
       return 0
```

Is there enough to perform this check? Or there is smarter way to check if the passed directory (relative or absolute) exists?

Cheers

Comment: Just modify to: `return os.path.isdir(full_path)` and remove the whole if/else block

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Yes, using `os.path.abspath()` will turn a relative path into an absolute path relative to the current working directory. Your code can be simplified (just return the `os.path.isdir()` call, it's a boolean already, no need to assign `get_path` when you can use `pass_dir` directly).

Comment: Also, what is the need of `get_path = pass_dir`. Just do `full_path = os.path.abspath(pass_dir)`